# Subdomains still pointing to www folder after setting up vhosts

Tags: apache, dns, directory, subdomain, vhosts

I setup an A record for my subdomain. Typing subdomain.domain.com in my browsers takes me to /var/www on my server. I created a virtual host for this subdomain, specifying the document root as /var/www/subdomain.domain.com. I restarted Apache, but subdomain.domain.com is still taking me to /var/www. Is there something wrong with my vhost configuration?

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/subdomain.domain.com"
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com
<Directory "/var/www/subdomain.domain.com">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Instead of the top line:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
```

I just needed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```